# How to write custom validation rules for Magento 2 product import CSV data?

Tags: magento2, products, validation, magento2.4.5, product-import

I am trying to write custom rules for Magento 2 product import data. For example Price must contain specific number of digits based on store view. How can I do such type of validations on csv data and add the error in the error report file same as Magento way.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code in di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product\Validator">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="validators" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="yourcustompricevalidator" xsi:type="object">VendorName\CustomModule\Model\Import\Product\Validator\PriceValidator</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

app/code/VendorName/CustomModule/Model/Import/Product/Validator/PriceValidator.php

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\CustomModule\Model\Import\Product\Validator;

use Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product\RowValidatorInterface;
use Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product\Validator\AbstractImportValidator;

class PriceValidator extends AbstractImportValidator implements RowValidatorInterface
{
    public function isValid($value)
    {
        $this->_clearMessages();
        if (!$value['price']) {
            $this->_addMessages(
                [
                    'YOUR CUSTOM MESSAGE'
                ]
            );
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Modify the **if (!$value['price']) {** logic.